# How to perform Excel ROUNDUP function in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2005

Hi how can we do Excel ROUNDUP function in SQL Server 2005 ?

Below is my test case:

**In Excel:**

=ROUNDUP(1/100,0)*0.25 = 1

=ROUNDUP(10/100,0)*0.25 = 1

**In SQL Server 2005:**

SELECT (ROUND(CAST(1 AS decimal(18,4))/100,0)) = 0.0000

which is really diffirent.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select ceiling(round(5.0/2.0,0.25)*0.25) --1

 select floor(round(5.0/2.0,0.25)*0.25) --0
```

**[Ceiling](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx)**

**[Floor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

```
    select ROUND(5.0/2.0,0.25)*0.25
```